# Passing parameters in crystal reports sql command query

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to add a parameter to SQL commands in Crystal report and it errors out. Below is my query

```
select r.ID as ActivityRequestID, count(c.ID) as ChangeCount from Change c join ActivityRequest r on c.ObjID=r.ID 
where (c.Class='ActivityRequest' and c.ChangeType='Modified' and (c.PropertyName='Definition' or c.PropertyName='Registration') and ({c.Performed} >={?ChangesSince} ) ) group by r.ID
```

I went to database expert and created the above command. Now when I try to save the command it gives me the error. 'Failed to retriever data from database. No value given for one or more parameters'. Now the user selects the parameter when the report loads and there is no hard coded value that I can give. Please tell me a way to fix the above problem.

Comment: The second-to-last sentence is unclear... Does the command work when you replace [?ChangesSince} with a constant date or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have inadvertently included a couple of braces where they are not needed, around `{c.performed}` - try this:

```
select r.ID as ActivityRequestID, 
       count(c.ID) as ChangeCount 
from Change c 
join ActivityRequest r on c.ObjID=r.ID 
where c.Class='ActivityRequest' and 
      c.ChangeType='Modified' and 
      (c.PropertyName='Definition' or 
       c.PropertyName='Registration') and 
      c.Performed >={?ChangesSince}  
group by r.ID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Can I ask you another question.Is it possible to make the parameter optional. I tried doing that, but the optional True False in the Edit parameter is disabled.

Comment: If you have included it as a selection condition in your SQL, I don't see how it could be optional - so no, not as far as I know, in these circumstances. (You could give it a very low default value instead.)